# NaN values when using pd.cut

Tags: python, nan

I have this dataframe with rows of EEG events. I made a column scaling the starting point of the events from 0 to 1. I am trying to bin these scaled times into 100 bins to start the analysis. I end up with 8 NaN values in the Timebins column. All of them have the exact value of 1 in the TimeScaled column. what could be the possible reason?

This is all I did:

```
scaler = MinMaxScaler()
TimeScaled = concatenated_df.groupby(['Subject','Session']).apply(lambda x: scaler.fit_transform(x[['Start']].values.astype(float))).reset_index()
TimeScaled.rename(columns={0: 'Time'}, inplace=True)
TimeScaled = TimeScaled.explode('Time').reset_index()
TimeScaled.loc[:,'Time'] =TimeScaled.Time.astype('float')

concatenated_df['TimeScaled'] = TimeScaled['Time'].values
bins = np.linspace(0, 1, 100)
labels = np.array(range(1,100))
concatenated_df['Timebins'] = pd.cut(concatenated_df.TimeScaled, bins=bins, labels=labels, include_lowest=True)
```

when I try this code to find null values:

```
concatenated_df.loc[concatenated_df['Timebins'].isna()]
```

I find the rows in the image:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3GOty.png)

I should probably mention that I also checked if the TimeScaled values in those line are maybe not exactly 1 but close to 1. This was not the case.

Comment: Remember that Python ranges always exclude the closing end.  Your `linspace` goes up to but does not include the value `1`.  Perhaps you should try`linspace(0,1.01,101)`.

Comment: But, there are many more 1s in the TimeScaled column. None of them have null values assigned to them as the Timebin. just these 8.